# Laravel fetch all the values of a column

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, eloquent, laravel-8

The `user_enabled_notifications` table has 2 rows of data. i wanted to fetch all the values in the `id` column.

```
$notificationData = UserEnabledNotifications::all();
```

`dump($notificationData['id']);` shows `Undefined index: id`

`dump($notificationData->id);` shows `Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance`

`dump($notificationData[0]['id']);` shows only 1 id. What else shall i try to fetch all the `id` column values in a single stretch.

However,    `dump($notificationData);` shows the complete data in table as given below.

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#337
  #items: array:4 [
    0 => App\Models\UserEnabledNotifications {#338
      #table: "user_enabled_notifications"
      #fillable: array:3 [
        0 => "userId"
        1 => "notificationTypesId"
        2 => "status"
      ]
      #connection: "pgsql"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      +preventsLazyLoading: false
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:7 [
        "id" => 1
        "userId" => 1
        "notificationTypesId" => 1
        "status" => true
        "deleted_at" => null
        "created_at" => null
        "updated_at" => null
      ]
      #original: array:7 [
        "id" => 1
        "userId" => 1
        "notificationTypesId" => 1
        "status" => true
        "deleted_at" => null
        "created_at" => null
        "updated_at" => null
      ]
      #changes: []
      #casts: array:1 [
        "deleted_at" => "datetime"
      ]
      #classCastCache: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: []
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #guarded: array:1 [
        0 => "*"
      ]
      #forceDeleting: false
      #enableLoggingModelsEvents: true
      #oldAttributes: []
    }
    1 => App\Models\UserEnabledNotifications {#339
      #table: "user_enabled_notifications"
      #fillable: array:3 [
        0 => "userId"
        1 => "notificationTypesId"
        2 => "status"
      ]
      #connection: "pgsql"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      +preventsLazyLoading: false
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:7 [
        "id" => 2
        "userId" => 1
        "notificationTypesId" => 2
        "status" => true
        "deleted_at" => null
        "created_at" => null
        "updated_at" => null
      ]
      #original: array:7 [
        "id" => 2
        "userId" => 1
        "notificationTypesId" => 2
        "status" => true
        "deleted_at" => null
        "created_at" => null
        "updated_at" => null
      ]
      #changes: []
      #casts: array:1 [
        "deleted_at" => "datetime"
      ]
      #classCastCache: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: []
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #guarded: array:1 [
        0 => "*"
      ]
      #forceDeleting: false
      #enableLoggingModelsEvents: true
      #oldAttributes: []
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$notificationData` is an object of type [Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-collections#introduction), a collection. If you want to get the id of individual elements. Pls do the followings:

```php
foreach ($notificationData as $notification) {
  dump($notification->id);
}

// Or
$notificationData->pluck('id')->toArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
// get your main collection with all the attributes...
$notificationData = UserEnabledNotifications::get();

// build your second collection with a subset of attributes. this new
// collection will be a collection of plain arrays, not UserEnabledNotifications models.
$subset = $notificationData->map(function ($notification) {
    return collect($notification->toArray())
        ->only(['id'])
        ->all();
});
dd($subset);
```

**OR**

```
$notificationData = $notificationData->pluck('id')->toArray();
dd($notificationData);
```

Answer (score 0):

all() gives you an collection (similar to array), so it has index (0 and positive integers) for keys

use **pluck()** to get all specific value for a key

```
$notificationData = UserEnabledNotifications::pluck('id');

print($notificationData) // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ...]
```